# How to get notifications for new comments in Gitlab merge requests discussions

Tags: gitlab

When I start a discussion linked to a merge request, I'd like to get notifications when someone adds a comment to the discussion.

Of course I'd like to avoid setting the notification level on *Watch* because it would also spam me for activities I'm not interested in.

Is it possible or is it a missing feature ?

Answer (score 4):

Check and see if you have this option in your user settings:

Settings >> Notifications >> Global Notification Level = Participate.

If you participate in the thread once, it seems like you'll be notified on new messages thereafter, only in that thread.

Comment: I already have this exact setting. Right below there is a box *Receive notifications about your own activity* that is unticked. I assume it notifies me when I do something on the repo, or I misunderstand it ?

Comment: You would be correct. By default you won't receive notifications when you contribute to the discussion. And I think by notifications Github mean emails, not quite pop-up notifications. I only get pop-up notifications from pipelines success/failure when I'm _on_ that specific page :/

Comment: You wrote *Github*, I assume you mean *GitLab*.

Comment: whups, yeap you are correct. I did in fact mean Git*lab*.